# Do Miles & More Frequent Traveller / Silver Members get Lounge Access?

Tags: lounges, star-alliance, miles-and-more, austrian-airlines

I have Frequent Traveller Status with the Miles & More programme and bought an economy ticket for my next flight with Austrian Airlines. The [Miles & More website](https://www.austrian.com/at/en/miles-and-more) seems to indicate that I can use the business lounge with this status, but the [Star Alliance website](https://miles-and-more.com/at/en/program/status-benefits/lounges.html) indicates that I need Gold Status (equivalent to M&M "Senator") for lounge access, whereas Frequent Traveller equates only to Silver.

Does that mean I get lounge access at Vienna for my Austrian flight but maybe not for other Star Alliance partners? Does this apply for my return flight from Heathrow as well?

Comment: Careful: *A Gold Status is not equivalent to M&M "Senator". There are distinct differences regarding lounge entry for inbound flights in important hubs in CH, AT and DE, for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Correct, lounge access for M&M Frequent Travellers is an M&M specific benefit, not Star Alliance related. So you get access to Lufthansa group lounges when you are flying on a Lufthansa group flight (this includes Lufthansa, Austrian, Swiss, Brussels and Eurowings).

In Heathrow you have access to the Lufthansa Business lounge (you can check the lounge finder at https://www.lufthansa.com/de/de/lounges)

Comment: Careful with Eurowings! Check the exact regulations here for entry: https://www.eurowings.com/en/your-rewards/loyalty-programs/miles-more/lounges.html